# Unexpected error when implementing FEM in MoL SpatialDiscretization

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, finite-element-method

I cannot figure out why the following piece of code

```
PDEs = {Derivative[1, 0][w][t, x] == w[t, x]/v[t, x], 
       Derivative[1, 0][v][t, x] == 0};

    IC = {w[0, x] == 0, v[0, x] == 1};

    BC = {w[t, 1] == 0, v[t, 1] == 1};


    AbsoluteTiming[
     evolution = 
       NDSolve[{PDEs, IC, BC}, {w, v}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
        Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
          "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
            "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}];]
```

results in

`NDSolve::femcnsd: The PDE coefficient w[x]/v[x] does not evaluate to a numeric scalar at the coordinate {0.5}; it evaluated to Indeterminate instead.`

instead of the profound result $w(t,x)=v(t,x)-1=0$.

Can anyone help?

PS: Replace `w[t, x]/v[t, x]` with `w[t, x]*v[t, x]` in the code, i.e.

```
 PDEs = {Derivative[1, 0][w][t, x] == w[t, x]*v[t, x], 
           Derivative[1, 0][v][t, x] == 0};

        IC = {w[0, x] == 0, v[0, x] == 1};

        BC = {w[t, 1] == 0, v[t, 1] == 1};
```

and it works just fine. It seems that my code understands `*` but not `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some rare cases of coupled DEs, `NDSolve` can not automatically figure out the ordering of the equations. This works:

```
PDEs = {Derivative[1, 0][w][t, x] == w[t, x]/v[t, x], 
   Derivative[1, 0][v][t, x] == 0};
IC = {w[0, x] == 0, v[0, x] == 1};
BC = {w[t, 1] == 0, v[t, 1] == 1};
AbsoluteTiming[
 evolution = NDSolveValue[{PDEs, IC, BC}, {w, v}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1},
    "DependentVariables" -> {w, v},
    Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
      "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01}}];]
```

Check the result:

```
Plot3D[#[t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}] & /@ evolution
```

[image]

You can find more information on this issue in the documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#898113620).